# Replace "Lunch Out, Lunch In" with duration in formula to give Time Out/In difference excluding Lunch

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding, worksheet-function, time-format

I currently have the following formula to track my work schedule. Time is put down in traditional format ie. `8:00 am`, and is then totaled to show hours worked as a whole number `8`, for 8 hrs worked:

```
=IF(D2="","",ROUND(IF(OR(C2="",B2=""),(D2-A2),(B2-A2)+(D2-C2))*24*4,0)/4)
```

A=Time In , B=Lunch Out , C=Lunch In , D=Time Out.

I would like to alter this to in two ways:

**1st.** Remove the ROUND function, I don't need it.

**2nd.** I don't need Lunch In and Lunch Out. I need column B to =Lunch, displayed as a number (`1` for one hour or, `.5` for half hour) to be subtracted from Time In and Time Out since we're not paid for lunch.

Comment: Can you show the example of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a ColumnE for Lunch, please try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(D2="","",(D2-A2)*24)-E2,"")
```

formatted as number.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a 24hr format to calculate with dates/times.

This should work for you:

```
A is time in, e.g. 08:00
B is time out, e.g. 16:30
C is lunch, e.g. 00:30 (duration in minutes)
D is the formula below, which calculates your paid working time


=((B2-A2)-C2)*24
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, this did work but gave me the time in a negative number.